# Why are `__init__.py` and `BUILD` needed inside TensorFlow's `models/tutorials/rnn/translate`?

Tags: tensorflow

Inside the `tensorflow/models/tutorials/rnn/translate` folder, we have a few files including `__init__.py` and `BUILD`.

Without `__init__.py` and `BUILD` files, the translate script can still manage to run.

What is the purpose of `__init__.py` and `BUILD` here? Are we supposed to install or build it using these two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`BUILD`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/BUILD) file supports using [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) for hermetic building and testing of the model code. In particular a `BUILD` file is present in that directory to define the integration test `translate_test.py` and its dependencies, so that we can run it on continuous integration system (e.g. Jenkins).

The [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9681f3fcbaee18ab3c175426a5c217cedd1613bf/tutorials/rnn/translate/__init__.py) file causes Python to treat that directory as a package. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/3574081) for a discussion of why `__init__.py` is often present in a Python source directory. While this file is not strictly necessary to invoke [`translate.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9681f3fcbaee18ab3c175426a5c217cedd1613bf/tutorials/rnn/translate/translate.py) directly from that directory, it is necessary if we want to import the code from `translate.py` into a different module.

(Note that when you run a Python binary through Bazel, the build system will automatically generate `__init__.py` files if they are missing. However, TensorFlow's repositories often have explicit `__init__.py` files  in Python source directories so that you can run the code without invoking Bazel.)